# message in mars lander parachute

Tags: message-recovery

I think there's a msg in the [parachute of the mars lander](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYQwuYZbA6o) , the guy in the vid seems to hint at it[image]

I converted this to binary with red=1 and white=0 starting from the three all-red sectors in the top left.
That file is [here](https://wiki.telavivmakers.org/index.php/File:Msg.tsv) .

So what's the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was posted on Reddit r/cryptography (edited slightly):

[What message did the Perseverance parachute have?](https://old.reddit.com/r/space/comments/lpzp7p/what_message_did_the_perseverance_parachute_have/goemk0m/)

> “Dare Mighty Things”. Inner circle, “Dare”. Next circle out, “Mighty”.... using 10 bits and correlating the binary number of each letter in the alphabet.
> Ignore the big patches of red. Red=1

> And the edge ring is "34° 11' 58" N 118° 10' 31" W", coordinates of JPL where the rover was built.

Comment: Since this is someone else's solution, shouldn't you have made this a Community Wiki? You can do so by clicking "edit" then "make community wiki".